# What is the difference between these 2 string array commands

Tags: java, android, arrays

What's difference between

```
String [] O = {};
```

and

```
String[] Ox = new String[3000];
```

How can I copy the strings from `Ox` to `O`?

Answer (score 4):

`O` is empty array and `Ox` has 3000 length, to copy `Ox` to `O` you have to use `copyOf()` api of `Arrays` class.

```
O = Arrays.copyOf(Ox, Ox.length);
```

`Arrays.copyOf()` create change the `O` array length to `3000` and copy all contents.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] O = {};
        String[] Ox = new String[3000];

        O = Arrays.copyOf(Ox, Ox.length);
        System.out.println("O array length : "+O.length);  // I am just printing length
    }
```

Output :

```
O array length : 3000
```

**Internal implementation of copyOf() api of Arrays class.**

```
public static char[]  copyOf(char[] original, int newLength) {
    char[] copy = new char[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
            Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

`Array` is `immutable` so you can not assign `3000 size array` to `size 0 array`, in implementation of `copyOf()` method java created new array  `char[] copy` and using `native` method copy content of `original` array to `copy` array.

So, in you code you can not directly copy `Ox` array contents to `O` array for that you have to create array of size 3000 or use `copyOf()` api of Java.

Answer (score 3):

In Java arrays are not mutable, thus you can not change the size of an array. Because you declare O as size 0 implicitly (the {} means its empty) it can not be filled.

You need to declare a new array of size 3000 (new String[3000]) and then use that

Answer (score 1):

`O` is an empty array, so you can't copy anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

With the following statement you declare a table O that is empty (size=0, no elements).

```
 String[] o = {};
```

If instead you write:

```
String[] o = {"this", "is", "a", "test"};
```

you have initialized table O to have size=4 and contain the four string elements "this", "is", "a" and "test".

Finally, if you initialize your table in the following way:

```
String[] o = new String[4];
```

you have declared that your array has size=4, but all four elements are null. Of course, you can later change the values of your array (eg. `o[3] = "test"`).

Now, if you want to copy the elements of one array to the other you can use the `Arrays.copyOf(o, o.length);` method, but in the following way :

```
String[] o = {"this", "is", "a", "test"};
String[] copy; // you don't have to (and shouldn't) initialize this variable to {}
copy = Arrays.copyOf(o, o.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of differences here:

1) String [] O = {};

this means to create a new `String[]` called `O` which is *initialized* with the data set contained in `{}`.  Since there is *no data*, O is "**empty**".

This means that `O.length = 0`, or put another way, this Array has no memory associated with it for storage purposes.

Since Arrays are immutable in java, you cannot do anything further with this array.

You could have done:

```
String[] O = {"bob","Cat","ralph"}

O.length // == 3
O[0] // bob
O[1] // Cat
O[2] // ralph

O[1] = "Sting"
O[1] // now set to Sting

O[4] = "Cause an Exception" // causes an index out of bounds exception
```

2)  `String[] O = new String[3000];`

In this case you have created a new `String[]` with 3000 "spaces" or "indices" available.  What this really means is that you can maintain references to 3000 String objects in this array.

So:

```
O.length; //3000 because that is the length of this array
     O[0] // will return null since we have not stored anything here
     O[0] = "My String"
     O[0] // now equals "My String"
     O[3001] // throws an index out of bounds exception
```

3)  How can you copy between them:

In short you cannot in this case.  Since array 1 (`String[] O = {}`)  is empty and has a length of 0 any attempt to copy to or from this array will result in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all - brings some new Information for me -
but

```
O = Arrays.copyOf(Ox, Ox.length);
```

from atish shimpi

helps to solve the Problem :))